# Interact with a shell based program through C++

Tags: c++, shell, expect, interactive

I am trying to write a C++ program in which it can interact with another shell-based program(commercial tool) and send commands and get the results back from it. 
I've heard about couple of options and I want to know the advantages/disadvantages of each of them.

1) I can use "expect" to make the job for me.
2) I can use the concept of IPC and shared memory (which I am familiar with) to do this.

I would appreciate if anyone has any idea about these how these two options work or have any other suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One things I've done which worked quite well was use `socketpair()` to create a socket, then use fork+exec to start the child process with its `stdin` and `stdout` redirected to the far end of the pair. Thereafter you just have a remote process connected via a bidirectional socket, which is pretty standard stuff (although you have to remember to tidy the child process up properly).